# Android - How can I view a sql database created in my app? I'm running it on the Android device in Eclipse

Tags: android

1. In the Eclipse look at the **File Explorer tab** (near the Console tab). Or look at menu `Window -> Show View -> Other... -> File Explorer`. **Emulator should be run**. In the **File Explorer** window go to the folder `data/data/[your_package_name]/databases/`. 
   There you can find your database. You can export it to the your computer. At the right top corner of the window there is a button `pull a file from device`. Select database, click that button and save a database on the computer.
2. Program `sqlite browser` can shows a data in the database. You can download it here. It is easy to use.
   Can any one suggest me that how can I view a sql database created in my app? I am running it on the Android device in Eclipse

Comment: Query your tables and display the results.

Comment: [HERE](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.techrepublic.com%2Fblog%2Fsoftware-engineer%2Fbrowse-sqlite-data-on-the-android-emulator%2F&ei=j8H4UvrDMs2JrAefyYDAAw&usg=AFQjCNH5Q4g_kxQh3WETobS-4YL4XYnICQ&sig2=vgF8SXcr8kFDyg3MdjiM2w&bvm=bv.60983673,d.bmk) is a useful link. consider googleing before asking quesions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your project in Emulator then you can view it in `/database/database` folder of your project's package name.

If you are running your project in real device then you can not view it directly unless your database is stored on external path like on SD card.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to first save your database to SD card

```
public static void saveDbFile() {

    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "/data/com.RareMediaCompany.BlueDolphinTest/databases/HeliosEmployeeTracker.db";
            String backupDBPath = "backUpheliosCurr.db";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB)
                        .getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB)
                        .getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();

            }
        }
        Log.i("save db", "db saved on sd card");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Then open your "Mozilla Firefox Browser" and add a "Add on" to the browser named "Sqlite Manager". Then just import that database to the Manager and you are ready to go